# An Interesting Combinatorics Problem Regarding Knockout Matches

Tags: combinatorics

8 teams are participating in a knockout match.So,the team whichever loses the match goes away.Such as, if 7 and 8 no team plays and 7 no team wins the match,then 8 no team goes away and 7 no team will play with 6 no team and then the winner (among 7 no and 6 no team )will play with the 5 no team and thus it will continue.So,how many different results are possible then ?
Source:Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad 2019
My try:
I don't know whether my answer is correct or not.I thought that for each match,there can be 2C1 different results.So,then the total different result may be( 2C1)^8 or 2^8.
So,please let me know the correct answer.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that in a knockout tournament with $8$ teams there are $7$ matches (since all but one team has to be knocked out)

Comment: What counts as a different "*result*"?  If the only thing we care about is who the final winner is, there are only eight results.  Do you always have the bottom two remaining teams play against each other at any given time?  If not, in what order are the games played?  Does the order in which the games are played matter too?